# Query MongoDb with Java and pass it to d3/javascript?

Tags: javascript, java

I want to create a chart where I can select a time period and query mongodb accordingly. I want to use Java to query MongoDb. I know how to connect MongoDb and Java but I'm not so clear about linking the java to my webpage(i.e. To pass the data from that java file to my webpage/javascript).

I know Ajax calls can be used to link to servlets, but I'm sort of lost. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the Java MongoDB driver to connect to and query MongoDB from within your Java application. https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/java/client/

You would make that data available to the browser (D3/JavaScript) the same way you would make any server-side data available to the browser. You could either add that data to the page as you are rendering the actual webpage, or you could return the data in response to an AJAX request.

Comment: I actually need help with linking java and my webpage. I'll make my question a bit clearer.

Comment: @user3270763 I added more info to my answer.

Comment: It's not necessary for me to use a Servlet then?

Comment: All data going from your java application on your server to your browser has to be rendered by some sort of servlet. I would suggest building a basic java webpage first to see how data gets rendered by the server, then this will probably make more sense to you. Also, if you drop the irrelevant "mongodb" and "d3" from your question and just search for examples on how to get data from java into javascript you will find tons of examples.

Comment: Okay, Thanks! I'll drop that part.